# Need to check for multiple variables (Or hide unpassed values) in Google Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

There may be a better way to do this, but I have a Google Chart that I have to pass 24 variables into.

The end goal is to only display the numbers that are actually passed, and ignore the ones that are not. I know this is possible if I do 24 if-statements, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do it.

Essentially i'm calling this function 
`function drawGoogFinanceChart(chartnamelong, chartobj) {`

Then i'm setting all the parameters to what is created. I do it this way, because otherwise the chart breaks (it can't handle undefined).

```js
    {
        var v1 = chartobj.onemil;
        var v2 = chartobj.halfmil
        var v3 = chartobj.onehundo;
        var v4 = chartobj.fiftythous;
        var v5 = chartobj.tenthous;
        var v6 = chartobj.ninethous;
        var v7 = chartobj.eightthous;
        var v8 = chartobj.seventhous;
        var v9 = chartobj.sixthous;
        var v10 = chartobj.fivethous;
        var v11 = chartobj.fourthous;
        var v12 = chartobj.threethous;
        var v13 = chartobj.twothous;
        var v14 = chartobj.onethous;
        var v15 = chartobj.ninehund;
        var v16 = chartobj.eighthund;
        var v17 = chartobj.sevenhund;
        var v18 = chartobj.sixhund;
        var v19 = chartobj.fivehund;
        var v20 = chartobj.fourhund;
        var v21 = chartobj.threehund;
        var v22 = chartobj.twohund;
        var v23 = chartobj.hund;
        var v24 = chartobj.other;
    }
```

Then I obviously put all the variables into the charts...

```js
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Amount', 'Respondents'],
['1 Million', v1],
['500,000', v2],
['100,000', v3],
['50,000', v4],
['10,000', v5],
['9,000', v6],
['8,000', v7],
['7,000', v8],
['6,000', v9],
['5,000', v10],
['4,000', v11],
['3,000', v12],
['2,000', v13],
['1,000', v14],
['900', v15],
['800', v16],
['700', v17],
['600', v18],
['500', v19],
['400', v20],
['300', v21],
['200', v22],
['100', v23],
['Other', v24]
]);
```

This will draw up a chart similar to this:
[image: Google Chart]

I'd rather not display the values that are zeros. I know I could do this if I did something like

`if (chartobj.onemil != undefined) {
data.push(['1 Million', v1]);
}`

But then i'd have to do that 24 times. I was just wondering if there was a cleaner way to do this (or an entirely different way to do it at all!)

Answer (score 0):

[Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with filter should do the job 
since Object.entries support is not that good, you should use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Polyfill)

```
// const obj = { foo: 'bar', baz: 42 };
// console.log(Object.entries(obj));
// [ ['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 42] ]

// filter will only return the arrays with value different than undefined
const data = Object.entrie(chartobj).filter(([key, value]) => value !== undefined);
google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data)
```